# Creating Accordion manually

Tags: html, css

i had tried to re-create and accordion style menu manually without using jQuery-UI library. Everything is working fine except when i click to open a box it opens immediately without any transition. I try to show hide each box by adding a class called open. Am generating data inside each  dynamically so the data will be changing each time and the data inside each  will be completely different.

"I DONT WANT  A SOLUTION INVOLVES ACCORDION" [sorry for typing in caps :-)]

I have setup this in jsFiddle. Can someone please take a look at this.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/2nfd9utt/
```

For sample code look, see below. 
Here is the HTML Structure i use.

```
<ul class="prfaccordion">
   <li>
      <h3 class="prfaccDetailsHeader"> Committees </h3>
      <div class="prfaccDetails">
         <ul>
            <li> Sample Data 1 </li>
            <li> Sample Data 2 </li>
            <li> Sample Data 3 </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h3 class="prfaccDetailsHeader"> Contributions </h3>
      <div class="prfaccDetails">
         <ul>
            <li> Sample Data 1 </li>
            <li> Sample Data 2 </li>
            <li> Sample Data 3 </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h3 class="prfaccDetailsHeader"> Areas </h3>
      <div class="prfaccDetails">
         <ul>
            <li> Sample Data 1 </li>
            <li> Sample Data 2 </li>
            <li> Sample Data 3 </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
</div>
```

Here is the style,

```
.prfaccordion{
 width: 150px;   
}

.prfgrybox {
    background: #eeeeee;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.prfaccordion li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
}

    ul.prfaccordion li h3 {
        background: #eeeeee url(images/downarr.png) no-repeat 95% 50%;
        padding: 6px 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        margin: 0px;
        color: #3a4f60;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

        ul.prfaccordion li h3.open {
            background: #eeeeee url(images/uparr.png) no-repeat 95% 50%;
            border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
            -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
        }

    ul.prfaccordion li .prfaccDetails {
        background: #fbfbfb;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
           font-size: 13px;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
        color: #5787ad;
        display: none;
          transition:all ease .5s;
            -moz-transition:all ease .5s;
            -webkit-transition:all ease .5s;
    }

        ul.prfaccordion li .prfaccDetails ul li {
            padding: 5px 0px 5px 14px;
            position: relative;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        }

            ul.prfaccordion li .prfaccDetails ul li a {
                font-size: 13px !important;
                color: #5787ad !important;
            }


            ul.prfaccordion li .prfaccDetails ul li:before {
                position: absolute;
                top: 9px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 8px;
                height: 8px;
                border-radius: 100%;
                -moz-border-radius: 100%;
                -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
                content: "";
                background: #b1c7cc;
            }

        ul.prfaccordion li .prfaccDetails.open {
            transition:all ease .5s;
            -moz-transition:all ease .5s;
            -webkit-transition:all ease .5s;
             display: block;
        }
}
```

And Here is the Script,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".prfaccDetailsHeader").click(function (event) {

                if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
                    $('.prfaccDetailsHeader').removeClass("open");
                    $('.prfaccDetails').removeClass("open");
                    return false;
                }

                $('.prfaccDetailsHeader').each(function (i, obj) {
                    $(this).removeClass('open');
                });

                $('.prfaccDetails').each(function (event) {
                    $(this).removeClass('open');
                });

                $(this).addClass("open");
                $(this).parent().find('.prfaccDetails').addClass("open");
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquerys [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method and pass in the parameter slow.

`.toggle("slow");`

Your jquery code would then look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".prfaccDetailsHeader").click(function (event) {
        $('.prfaccDetailsHeader').each(function (i, obj) {
            $(this).removeClass('open');
        });
        $('.prfaccDetails').each(function (event) {
            $(this).removeClass('open');
        });
        $(this).parent().find('.prfaccDetails').toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

and you can remove some of your css. Such as transitions and the like.
[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nfd9utt/33/)

I include this answer because OP didnt explicitly say he wanted to use transitions, only that he didnt want to use `jquery-ui`.

Comment: sorry could you elaborate?

Comment: I thought OP didn't want JQuery

Comment: He doesnt want jquery-ui but he is clearly using jquery

Comment: It would be slideToggle(). But yes, the OP seems to want to do this with  css transitions.

Comment: Yes. i just want to add/remove class - i want to accomplish this by making change in css.

Comment: @KRIZTE elaborated on previous answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate between `display: none;` and `display: block;`. Instead of hiding your element with `display: none` you could hide it by adding `max-height: 0px` and `overflow:hidden`.

In the style snippet for when the element is opened you instead add e.g. `max-height: 1000px;` (the max-height should be the absolute maximum height your element is allowed to be)

Note: The reason I am choosing to animate `max-height` instead of just `height` is because css transitions can't animate the height if it's dynamic (i.e. height is set to auto or 100%). This is solved by instead animating the max-height of the element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".prfaccDetailsHeader").click(function(event) {

    if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $('.prfaccDetailsHeader').removeClass("open");
      $('.prfaccDetails').removeClass("open");
      return false;
    }

    $('.prfaccDetailsHeader').each(function(i, obj) {
      $(this).removeClass('open');
    });

    $('.prfaccDetails').each(function(event) {
      $(this).removeClass('open');
    });

    $(this).addClass("open");
    $(this).parent().find('.prfaccDetails').addClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
.prfaccordion {
  width: 150px;
}
.prfgrybox {
  background: #eeeeee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.prfaccordion li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
}
ul.prfaccordion li h3 {
  background: #eeeeee url(images/downarr.png) no-repeat 95% 50%;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #3a4f60;
  font-size: 15px;
}
ul.prfaccordion li h3.open {
  background: #eeeeee url(images/uparr.png) no-repeat 95% 50%;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
}
ul.prfaccordion li .prfaccDetails {
  background: #fbfbfb;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
  color: #5787ad;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all ease .5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .5s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
}
ul.prfaccordion li .prfaccDetails ul li {
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 14px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
ul.prfaccordion li .prfaccDetails ul li a {
  font-size: 13px !important;
  color: #5787ad !important;
}
ul.prfaccordion li .prfaccDetails ul li:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  content: "";
  background: #b1c7cc;
}
ul.prfaccordion li .prfaccDetails.open {
  max-height: 100px;
  transition: all ease .5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .5s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
  display: block;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="prfaccordion">
  <li>
    <h3 class="prfaccDetailsHeader"> Committees </h3>
    <div class="prfaccDetails">
      <ul>
        <li>Sample Data 1</li>
        <li>Sample Data 2</li>
        <li>Sample Data 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 class="prfaccDetailsHeader"> Contributions </h3>
    <div class="prfaccDetails">
      <ul>
        <li>Sample Data 1</li>
        <li>Sample Data 2</li>
        <li>Sample Data 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 class="prfaccDetailsHeader"> Areas </h3>
    <div class="prfaccDetails">
      <ul>
        <li>Sample Data 1</li>
        <li>Sample Data 2</li>
        <li>Sample Data 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to Natalie's. However, I couldn't get Natalie's to work using the "Run code snippet", so I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nfd9utt/16/). You wanted the accordion to slide, so you needed to set heights instead of display block and none.

```
.prfaccordion{
 width: 150px;   
}

.prfgrybox {
    background: #eeeeee;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.prfaccordion li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
}

    ul.prfaccordion li h3 {
        background: #eeeeee url(images/downarr.png) no-repeat 95% 50%;
        padding: 6px 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        margin: 0px;
        color: #3a4f60;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

        ul.prfaccordion li h3.open {
            background: #eeeeee url(images/uparr.png) no-repeat 95% 50%;
            border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
            -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
        }

    ul.prfaccordion li .prfaccDetails {
        background: #fbfbfb;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
           font-size: 13px;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
        color: #5787ad;
        max-height:0; 
        overflow:hidden;
          transition:all .5s ease;
            -moz-transition:all .5s ease;
            -webkit-transition:all .5s ease;
    }

        ul.prfaccordion li .prfaccDetails ul li {
            padding: 5px 0px 5px 14px;
            position: relative;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        }

            ul.prfaccordion li .prfaccDetails ul li a {
                font-size: 13px !important;
                color: #5787ad !important;
            }


            ul.prfaccordion li .prfaccDetails ul li:before {
                position: absolute;
                top: 9px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 8px;
                height: 8px;
                border-radius: 100%;
                -moz-border-radius: 100%;
                -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
                content: "";
                background: #b1c7cc;
            }

        ul.prfaccordion li .prfaccDetails.open {
            transition:all .5s ease;
            -moz-transition:all .5s ease;
            -webkit-transition:all .5s ease;
            max-height:100px;
        }
}
```

(I had this written before I noticed Natalie's answer, so I thought I'd post it anwyway)

Comment: This works! but i have mentioned in my question that the data generated in each box is dynamic and it changes!

Comment: @KRIZTE you can increase the max-height from 100px to 1000px; however, I did notice that the animation doesn't work quite as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this simple code to make your's work.

```js
$('.prfaccordion').find('h3').on('click',function(){     
        var _target = $(this).parent().find('> div');
        if($(_target).is(':visible')){
            $(_target).slideUp(500);
        }
        else {
            $(_target).slideDown(500);
        }
    });
```

```css
.prfaccordion {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    list-style: none;
}
.prfaccordion li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%; 
}
.prfaccordion li > h3 {
    background: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
.prfaccordion li > div {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="prfaccordion">
   <li>
      <h3> Committees </h3>
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li> Sample Data 1 </li>
            <li> Sample Data 2 </li>
            <li> Sample Data 3 </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h3> Committees 123 </h3>
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li> Sample Data 1 </li>
            <li> Sample Data 2 </li>
            <li> Sample Data 3 </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```